# BaseModel Implementation for a language in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a development tool for a language in eclipse . I completed the UI part now I need to do the second module called 'core' . when I read through eclipse plug-in development and jdt plug-in development in eclipse documentation I saw something called Ibasemodel and Ijavamodel. is there any example for developing core of development tool or for base model implementation for a language

Comment: You may want to consider [Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). Using JDT as a template for an eclipse IDE of a programming language is a bit out of date. You will get some things for free when using Xtext you would otherwise need to work hard for.

Comment: Xtext is not a good choice for this.. because i am not developing a language.. here the language is already developed.. i need to develop just an ide

Comment: Xtext can also be used for existing languages. You would have to model the existing language in an Xtext grammar. But this might not be trivial. Another suggestion is using EMF as the foundation for your IDE instead of the pojo used by JDT. This is what Xtext will use under the hood. This will already give you some nice features (outlines, compare and merge for example) without much cost.

Comment: ok.. but my language is extending the features of java .. and i need all java features to this. and i reffer the source code of jdt .. but it doesn't give anything. actualy i am realy new to this.. i dont have any idea where to begin

Comment: check this link http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.7.0/ it will give full source code